# I am trying to set a SSI or server side include

Tags: html, ssi

I am familiar with SSI and have it implemented on my site with no problems.

I want to change the way it's calling up files though.

I have monthly changes to my website and they are in a file set like `/2012/august/home.shtml` and when it calls up it's calling up the ssi it's calling from the august folder with something like this `#include file="bottomad.html"`

But I want to be able to change all months at once so I want to call it from my main public_html folder where my index page lies. I tried to like so. < !--#include file="/bottomad.shtml" -- > and that didn't work.

Should I do it like this < !--#include file="http://www.grossmag.com/bottomad.html" -- >?
The code directly above did not work and my fix is listed below. So far I have not found a .shtml extension that will call up a file in a directory that the source file is listed in or from a folder in the same directory as the source file.

Comment: i tried using the last example i listed it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by changing the file extension from .shtml to .php and then I called up the files through a callup I found at this link http://www.htmlforums.com/html-xhtml/t-guide-to-server-side-includesdynamic-contentupdating-pages-at-once-139520.html.  It is a php file include. I used two different ones to accomplish what I was going for. The first one was, < ?php include("menu.html"); ? > , which allowed me to call up files in the same folder my original file calling it up was in.

EX: file grossmag.com/2012/september/home.php would call up a specific menu for that given month at all times. With that line of code it would call from here: grossmag.com/2012/september/menu.html

This second code was what I was really looking for:
    < ?php
     $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
     $path .= "/linkbar.html";
     include_once($path);
     ? >

I wanted a line of code that would allow me to use one source file to change all pages in every folder. In my case it was for the footer, left and right sides, and a top navigation bar. The code I just listed allowed me to call it from the main public_html file.

EX: 
grossmag.com/2012/september/home.php &
grossmag.com/2012/august/home.php could both call the navigation bar etc. from grossmag.com/linkbar.html

The normal shtml include will not work for the first example when you switch to the .php extension. I hope this is helpful to anyone else having this problem. If you need further instructions or examples feel free to email me for help. jeremy.grossmag@gmail.com or if you need immediate help jeremy@vulgarmediaproductions.com